# Android - Splits screen for two applications

Tags: android, multitasking

In my application the user browse in a list of surveys and when clicking on one item in the listview the application starts a browser with a link to fill the survey.
In the same time the activity goes to the back and the user sees only the browser window.

Recently I saw many articles that both iOS8 and latest version of android allows to split the screen (in tablets) and running two activities in parallel.

I will to implement this behavior in my application, so when the user click on item in the listview, the screen will split: one part of the screen will contain my application and the second one will be the browser, so the user will be able to fill the survey and continue using my application.

Is there any way which I can achieve this behavior? Any kind of third party libraries or even in the new versions of the android SDK?

Answer (score 3):

> latest version of android allows to split the screen (in tablets) and running two activities in parallel

No, it does not.

Certain device manufacturers allow *users* to spawn a second app. And it may be that there are hooks in the manufacturer-specific SDKs (e.g., Samsung Mobile SDK) that would allow your app to spawn a second app. But at the present time, this is not a core capability of Android itself.

Comment: @galvan: I have no idea. A quick search of the Internet suggests that [this is not in iOS8 either](http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/12/5803210/ipad-split-screen-multitasking-hidden-in-ios-8-beta-video), though it may come in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3rd party libaray, you can split your activity into two panes using fragments. The left pane shows a listview fragment while the right one show a `WebView` in its own fragment. The advantage is that the user never leave your app.